# What software can I use in order to extract this pattern from music?

Tags: software, pitch, engineering

**Overall goal:** To input a song and output certain variables that will allow me to find quantitative patterns between songs.

Example: the time between highest and lowest pitches (in seconds) in a song.

Is there any software that can help me do this?

I have experience in programming so if there is some open-source option that might need a little modifying I am not opposed to that.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention that you have experience in programming, the [Essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/) library might fit your need.

> Essentia is an open-source C++ library for audio analysis and
>   audio-based music information retrieval released under the Affero
>   GPLv3 license (also available under proprietary license upon request).
>   It contains an extensive collection of reusable algorithms which
>   implement audio input/output functionality, standard digital signal
>   processing blocks, statistical characterization of data, and a large
>   set of spectral, temporal, tonal and high-level music descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

[Processing](https://processing.org/) has good sound libraries such as [Minim](http://code.compartmental.net/) and apparently a new factory library check [this link](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/index.html).